# How to find who is boss of department in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I would like to create a stored procedure to find who is the boss of department.
All managers are contained in department with prefix "_Head".

I have two tables with this structure and use SQL Server 2014.

SQL Server tables:

Person

```
PersonID | DepartID | PersonName
---------+----------+----------------------
  138    |   110    | RootManager
  248    |    90    | Manager1
   63    |    73    | User1
  218    |    73    | User2
  216    |    96    | Manager2
  161    |    93    | Manager3
  222    |    93    | Manager4
  118    |    23    | User3
  160    |    23    | User4
  259    |    86    | User5
```

Updated:

```
PersonID - PK
Person.DepartID = Depart.DepartID - FK
```

Depart

```
DepartID | ParentID | DepartName
---------+----------+--------------
   77    | NULL     | NULL
  100    | 77       | _Head of Root
   73    | 77       | Dep1
   90    | 73       | _Head of Dep1
   98    | 77       | Dep2
   96    | 98       | _Head of Dep2
   23    | 98       | SubDep2
   93    | 23       | _Head of SubDep2
   86    | 77       | Dep3
```

Updated:

```
DepartID - PK
Depart.ParentID = Depart.DepartID - FK
Depart.DepartID = Person.DepartID - FK
```

"_Head of something" can contains randomize characters without previous departname

e.g: "_Head of SubDep2" can be "_Head of Department XXX/YYY"

**TreeView:**

```
ROOT [DepartID = 77, ParentID = NULL]
 |- _Head of Root [DepartID = 110, ParentID = 77]
    |- RootManager [PersonID = 138, DepartId = 110]
 |- Dep1 [DepartID = 73, ParentID = 77]
    |- _Head of Dep1 [DepartID = 90, ParentID = 73]
        |- Manager1 [PersonID = 248, DepartId = 90]
    |- User1 [PersonID = 63, DepartId = 73]
    |- User2 [PersonID = 218, DepartId = 73]
 |- Dep2 [DepartID = 98, ParentID = 77]
    |- _Head of Dep2 [DepartID = 96, ParentID = 98]
        |- Manager2 [PersonID = 216, DepartId = 96]
    |- SubDep2 [DepartID = 23, ParentID = 98]
        |- _Head of SubDep2 [DepartID = 93, ParentID = 23]
            |- Manager3 [PersonID = 161, DepartId = 93]
            |- Manager4 [PersonID = 222, DepartId = 93]
        |- User3 [PersonID = 118, DepartId = 23]
        |- User4 [PersonID = 160, DepartId = 23]
 |- Dep3 [DepartID = 86, ParentID = 77]
    |- User5 [PersonID = 259, DepartId = 86]
```

Desired result:

- User1,User2 = Manager1 **[PersonID = 248]**
- User3,User4 = Manager3, Manager4 **[PersonID = 161, 222]**
- User5 = RootManager **[PersonID = 138]**
- Manager1, Manager2 = RootManager **[PersonID = 138]**
- Manager3 = Manager2 **[PersonID = 216]**

**I tried:**

SQL query with INNER JOIN but it work only for one level.

SQL with CTE, I combined the Department table, but I cannot combine with Person table.

Can somebody please help me with this topic?

Many thanks for support time

Comment: Seems like you should be fixing your design. The user's department shouldn't be `'_Head of Dep1'`, it should just be `'Dep1'`, and another column should denote who the head is. Probably that column should *actually* be in your department table, as a foreign key back to the employee table. The design you have at the moment is breaking normal form, as the data point contains two pieces of information; what department the person is part of, and if they are the head of that department or not.

Comment: Fix the data model!  If you are not going to store the actual data model, then store the "path" to the subdepartment.  For instance `'/'`, `'/dept1'`, `'/debt1/subdept1'`

Comment: @JarolPet I've provided a solution and fiddle to test with. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend revisiting and normalizing your database design. In the downtime if this is a database that is in use, using views as an abstraction to query data from can provide a seamless change until you have revisited the model. Once the model update is complete, simply update the view and all applications using the view would not need to be changed.

With your current Design, the following query will assist in determining the managers based on the pattern for identifying heads of departments:

### Approach 1 [Recommended]

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Person (
>   PersonID INTEGER,
>   DepartID INTEGER,
>   PersonName VARCHAR(11)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Person
>   (PersonID, DepartID, PersonName)
> VALUES
>   ('138', '110', 'RootManager'),
>   ('248', '90', 'Manager1'),
>   ('63', '73', 'User1'),
>   ('218', '73', 'User2'),
>   ('216', '96', 'Manager2'),
>   ('161', '93', 'Manager3'),
>   ('222', '93', 'Manager4'),
>   ('118', '23', 'User3'),
>   ('160', '23', 'User4'),
>   ('259', '86', 'User5');
>   
>   
>
> CREATE TABLE Depart (
>   DepartID INTEGER,
>   ParentID VARCHAR(4),
>   DepartName VARCHAR(16)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Depart
>   (DepartID, ParentID, DepartName)
> VALUES
>   ('77', NULL, NULL),
>   ('100', '77', '_Head of Root'),
>   ('73', '77', 'Dep1'),
>   ('90', '73', '_Head of Dep1'),
>   ('98', '77', 'Dep2'),
>   ('96', '98', '_Head of Dep2'),
>   ('23', '98', 'SubDep2'),
>   ('93', '23', '_Head of SubDep2'),
>   ('86', '77', 'Dep3');
> GO
> ```

19 rows affected

> 

> ```
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_GetManager
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROC sp_GetManager (@Name VARCHAR(20))
> AS
> BEGIN
> DECLARE @ManagerResult TABLE(PersonId INTEGER, PersonName VARCHAR(20));
>
> INSERT INTO @ManagerResult
> SELECT 
>     p.PersonId, 
>     p.PersonName
> FROM 
> Person p 
> WHERE p.DepartId in ( 
>     SELECT d.DepartId from Depart d 
>     WHERE d.DepartName IN (
>        SELECT  CONCAT('_Head of ',d1.DepartName) FROM
>        Depart d1
>        INNER JOIN Person p1 on p1.DepartId = d1.DepartId
>        WHERE p1.PersonName = @Name
>     )
>     
>     
>  )
>
>
> IF EXISTS(
>    Select PersonId from @ManagerResult
> )
> SELECT * from @ManagerResult
> ELSE
> SELECT p.PersonId, p.PersonName FROM Person p where p.PersonName='RootManager'
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User1'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      248 | Manager1
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User2'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      248 | Manager1
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager3'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User5'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User3'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      161 | Manager3  
>      222 | Manager4
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User4'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      161 | Manager3  
>      222 | Manager4
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager1'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager2'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9f6de77491e8ff4b51c4505562edeba)*

### Approach 2

It seems more tedious but if you intend to traverse the tree with your initial recursive approach then this attempt may guide you to traverse the hierarchy based on your foreign keys

> ```
> select @@version;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU6) (KB4563110) - 15.0.4053.23 (X64) <br>        Jul 25 2020 11:26:55 <br>        Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation<br>        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)<br> |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Person (
>   PersonID INTEGER,
>   DepartID INTEGER,
>   PersonName VARCHAR(11)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Person
>   (PersonID, DepartID, PersonName)
> VALUES
>   ('138', '110', 'RootManager'),
>   ('248', '90', 'Manager1'),
>   ('63', '73', 'User1'),
>   ('218', '73', 'User2'),
>   ('216', '96', 'Manager2'),
>   ('161', '93', 'Manager3'),
>   ('222', '93', 'Manager4'),
>   ('118', '23', 'User3'),
>   ('160', '23', 'User4'),
>   ('259', '86', 'User5');
>   
>   
>
> CREATE TABLE Depart (
>   DepartID INTEGER,
>   ParentID VARCHAR(4),
>   DepartName VARCHAR(16)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Depart
>   (DepartID, ParentID, DepartName)
> VALUES
>   ('77', NULL, NULL),
>   ('100', '77', '_Head of Root'),
>   ('73', '77', 'Dep1'),
>   ('90', '73', '_Head of Dep1'),
>   ('98', '77', 'Dep2'),
>   ('96', '98', '_Head of Dep2'),
>   ('23', '98', 'SubDep2'),
>   ('93', '23', '_Head of SubDep2'),
>   ('86', '77', 'Dep3');
> GO
> ```

19 rows affected

> 

> ```
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_GetManager
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROC sp_GetManager(@Name VARCHAR(20))
> AS
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE @ManagerResult TABLE(PersonId INTEGER, PersonName VARCHAR(20), ManagementLevel INTEGER);
> DECLARE @PersonId INTEGER, @PersonDepartmentId INTEGER;
>
> SELECT @PersonId = p.PersonId , @PersonDepartmentId = p.DepartId  FROM Person p 
>
>   WHERE p.PersonName  = @Name;
>
>    
>     WITH 
> head_of_department AS  (
>    SELECT d.DepartId, d.ParentId, d.DepartName, 0 as Level
>    FROM Depart d WHERE d.DepartId = @PersonDepartmentId
>    UNION ALL
>    SELECT d.DepartId, d.ParentId, d.DepartName, Level+1 as Level
>    FROM Depart d 
>    INNER JOIN head_of_department hod on d.DepartId = hod.ParentId
>    WHERE d.ParentId is NOT NULL  
> ),
> including_sub_department AS (
>    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
>        SELECT * from head_of_department
>        UNION ALL
>        SELECT d.DepartId, d.ParentId, d.DepartName, hod.Level
>        FROM Depart d 
>        INNER JOIN head_of_department hod on hod.DepartId = d.ParentId
>        
>    ) t WHERE t.DepartName LIKE '_Head of%'
> )
> INSERT INTO @ManagerResult
> select   p.PersonId, p.PersonName ,d.Level
> from including_sub_department d
> INNER JOIN Person p on d.DepartId = p.DepartId
> WHERE 
>  d.DepartId <> @PersonDepartmentId;
>
> DECLARE @MinManagementLevel INTEGER;
>
> IF EXISTS(
>    Select PersonId from @ManagerResult
> )
> BEGIN
> SELECT @MinManagementLevel=MIN(ManagementLevel) FROM @ManagerResult;
> SELECT PersonId, PersonName from @ManagerResult WHERE ManagementLevel = @MinManagementLevel;
> END
> ELSE
> SELECT p.PersonId, p.PersonName FROM Person p where p.PersonName='RootManager'
>
>     
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User1'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      248 | Manager1
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User2'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      248 | Manager1
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager3'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      216 | Manager2
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User5'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User3'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      161 | Manager3  
>      222 | Manager4
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'User4'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName
> -------: | :---------
>      161 | Manager3  
>      222 | Manager4
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager1'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

> ```
> exec sp_GetManager 'Manager2'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonId | PersonName 
> -------: | :----------
>      138 | RootManager
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9df0fe2cceae1603d511fb948863b80)*

Comment: Many thanks, your solution works. But I have this more complicated, department with prefix "_Head of some" the name after "_Head of" not the same as DepartName, in most cases I have name "_Head of Dep1 XXX/YYY" or "_Head of Department 1" and this items are only for better view (categorized). I checked database and tables contains PK and FK. I updated my first post, can you check again, please ?

Comment: @JarolPet I've updated Approach 2 that traverses keys and filters based on "_Head of" prefix

Comment: Many thank for your update, now it works without problem....Very good work!!!